# select object to edit

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a simple view function that's designed to allow the user to choose from items listed in an html table (records). Clicking on a record should divert the user to the template from which he can edit that specific record. The code is as follows:

```
def edit_record(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                a=ProjectRecord.objects.get()
                form = RecordForm(request.POST, instance=a)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
                a=ProjectRecord.objects.get()
                form = RecordForm(instance=a)
        return render_to_response('productionModulewire.html', {'form': form})
```

The problem is that the function works perfectly well ONLY so long as there is only 1 record in the database. As soon as I add another, I get a multiple returned item error.
I suspect it has something to do with "objects.get()" but I don't know how to correctly structure the view?

The url is simple (perhaps too much so):

```
(r'^edit/', edit_record),
```

and the model looks like this:

```
class ProjectRecord(models.Model): 
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES)
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    market = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MARKET_CHOICES)
    agencyID = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    clientID = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    prjmanager = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    acclead = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    artdirector = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    prdlead = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    intlead = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    prjname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    prjstatus = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    as_of = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    target_studio = models.DateField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    mech_return = models.DateField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    comp_return = models.DateField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    target_release = models.DateField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    record_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    record_modified = models.DateTimeField()
    studio_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    studio_process = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, choices=PROCESS_CHOICES)
    to_studio = models.DateTimeField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    from_studio = models.DateTimeField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    studio_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    studio_process2 = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, choices=PROCESS_CHOICES)
    to_studio2 = models.DateTimeField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    from_studio2 = models.DateTimeField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    upload_pdf = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    upload_achive = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.prjname

    class Admin: 
        pass
```

from which the model form "RecordForm" was derived.

Comment: The built-in admin interface does this for you completely automatically without writing any code at all.  Why are you writing this transaction yourself when you already have it working correctly in the admin interface?

Comment: Because I'm trying to customize the environment for a sizable number of end users. For instance, this particular record database will be only one of many "stand alone" modules that can be called by the user. The proposed functionality calls for the user to be able to open, and work on, multiple "modules" simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing about `get` is "get what?"

When you say

```
a=ProjectRecord.objects.get()
```

you neglected to provide any selection criteria.  Which row do you want from the database?

Which row?  Hmmmm... How does the `GET` transaction know which row is going to be edited?

Usually, we put that in the URL.

So, you'll need to update your `urls.py` to include the record ID on the URL path.  You'll need to update your view function definition to accept this record ID.  Finally, you'll need to update GET and POST to use this record identification which came from the URL.

---

Update `urls.py` to include the object id.  See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^class/(?P<object_id>\d+?)/$', 'app.views.edit_record'),
```

Update your view function

```
def edit_record( request, object_id = None ):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if object_id is None:
            return Http_404
        ProjectRecord.objects.get( pk = int(object_id) )

    etc.
```

Comment: didn't know about passing values through url (I know... damn newbies :-). A little study in that area yielded gold! Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @kjarsenal: Be sure to accept one of the answers that helped you with that.

Comment: I just clicked the checkmark on the upper left. I assume that is what's called for. Thank you.

Comment: @kjarsenal: There's a really good FAQ for the site that explains how it works and why that's advantageous to people like you who want answers to questions.  Consider that time spent reading the FAQ might be valuable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to tell what you need to change, but your guess is correct, the problem is with your `ProjectRecord.objects.get()` call.

You should be passing some sort of information to get in order to limit the list down to one.

In most cases, you will need:

```
ProjectRecord.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Where `id` is the primary key value of the `ProjectRecord` you are trying to edit.

Could you show the relevant code from your `urls.py` as well as more information on your `ProjectRecord` model?

Comment: Thanks all for the assistance. I edited the original post so that it contains more code. Hope it helps.